# How can I get the count of elements in a dispatch_queue

Tags: ios, count, dispatch

I have created a dispatch queue for sending network data, such as messages or pictures. One block is for sending one message or picture. And put them in the dispatch queue. When the socket did send a message or picture, I Want to check how many blocks are still in the dispatch queue. Is there any way to do that? Thanks!